# Laravel upload multiple files

Tags: laravel, controller, upload

I'm building a gallery with multiple files functionality.

So far I'm having two issues, but let's paste my code first.

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $gallery = new GalleryImage();

  if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $images = $request->file('image');
    foreach($images as $image) {
      $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
      $name = time() . '-' . $path;
      $gallery->image = $image->move(public_path().'/uploads/temp/', $name);
      //$gallery->image = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/gallery-images', $name);
    }
  }

  $gallery->gallery_id = $request->gallery_id;

  $gallery->save();

  return back()->with('success_message','Images has been uploaded!');
}
```

View blade:

```
    <form action="{{ route('gallery-images.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="gallery_id" value="{{ $gallery->id }}">
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="id_imageGallery" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

My first issue when I have my code like this and upload three files, it's successfully storing the files into /uploads/temp directory, but in my database I can see there's only one image uploaded, instead of three.

My second issue is when I change my code and use the commented part (because I want to store those three images into Storage):

```
$gallery->image = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/gallery-images', $name);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Call to a member function storeAs() on array
```

How can I upload those multiple images into the Storage folder and record them all into the database?

-- EDIT --
I've solved my first issue!

I've simply put the save method and other details inside the loop. I've should have thought about this before :)

Here's my updated code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


  if($request->hasFile('image')) {

    $images = $request->file('image');
    foreach($images as $image) {
      $gallery = new GalleryImage();
      $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
      $name = time() . '-' . $path;
      $gallery->image = $image->move(public_path().'/uploads/temp/', $name);
      //$gallery->image = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/gallery-images', $name);

      $gallery->gallery_id = $request->gallery_id;
      $gallery->save();
    }
  }


  return back()->with('success_message','Images has been uploaded!');
}
```

Now only thing to do is how to store them into File Storage, instead of the public_path and avoid that error:

```
Call to a member function storeAs() on array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solved the issues and I'm posting it, so it may be useful for some.

Here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  if($request->hasFile('image')) {

    foreach($request->image as $image) {
      $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
      $name = time() . '-' . $path;

      $gallery = new GalleryImage();
      $gallery->image = $image->storeAs('public/gallery-images', $name);
      $gallery->gallery_id = $request->gallery_id;
      $gallery->save();
    }
  }

  return back()->with('success_message','The images have been uploaded!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement using the following code, it will give uploaded files url in serialized format

```
    public static function upload_file($file){
        $file_name = time();
        $file_name .= rand();
        $file_name = sha1($file_name);
        if ($file) {
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move(public_path() . "/uploads", $file_name . "." . $ext);
            $local_url = $file_name . "." . $ext;
            $s3_url = url('/').'/uploads/'.$local_url;
            return $s3_url;
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static function upload_multiple_files($files){
        if(is_array($files)){
            $return_array = array();
            foreach ($files as $file){
                if(!empty($file)){
                    $return_array[] = self::upload_file($file);
                }else{
                    $return_array[] = '';
                }
            }
            return serialize($return_array);
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too complicated and not related with the issue.

Comment: I've figured out myself how to store the multiple files into the database too. Only thing to do is how to store them into File Storage, instead of the public_path. Check my updated main thread.

Answer (score 0):

//I have updated and commented your code. Try it, It should work.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->hasFile('image')) {

        $images = $request->file('image');
        foreach($images as $image) {
          $gallery = new GalleryImage();
          // laravel auto manages unique name and extension of file.
          $gallery->image = $image->store('gallery-images', 'public'); 
          $gallery->gallery_id = $request->gallery_id;
          $gallery->save();
        }
      }
      return back()->with('success_message','Images has been uploaded!');
    }
```

Comment: Please check my answer. I've solved the issue. By the way, I've just checked your solution and it has mistakes. 

**store('gallery-images', 'public');**  you're not passing the variable here and also it's very crucial to upload the image in user friendly file, not coded

Comment: There is no mistake in my code. All you need to pass is folder name and scope to store function. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-visibility  you can refer to this link. And congratulations for solving on your own. Happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Happy coding you too! :)