# How to upload many images in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I need to upload many of pictures in Laravel.
HTML Blade:

```
<form action="uploadImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image0" id="image">
    <input type="file" name="image1" id="image">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

and Laravel Controller:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count(collect($request)) - 1; $i++) {
        $image = $request->image.$i;
        $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if ($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "jpeg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "gif" && $ext != "webp") {
            return "no";
        }
        $imageName = \Str::random(20).".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path("images"), $imageName);
    }
```

Laravel return error: Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

What could be wrong here?

clarification:

- The code works for one image if I take the code from the loop and set $request->image0 or 1 etc. instead of $request->image.$i
- minus 1 from count(collect($request)) in the loop is because the last element of $request is a token.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111099/9556193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$request->file('image' . $i)` to get the image instead of `$request->image.$i`.

Your code converts the `UploadedFile` to a `string` and append `$i` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can easily change the name of the file inputs to an array version like:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image">
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image2">
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image3">
...
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image1000">
```